# Improving MySQL query performance for a large database

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-performance

have a simple query that do a join between two table. The main table has a date field that my query filter by a range of dates. But for a month period my main table has 37412 datas and for this values has others 914 794 items in child table. That just for a month period, for all time the child table has more than 35 975 568 items.

A simple join, like that, filtering by a range date is so slow:

```
select  count(i.BrandId) from projectitem i  
inner join project p on i.ProjectId = p.Id 
where (p.Date between "2019-07-01 00:00:00" AND "2019-07-30 23:59:59");
```

[image: query explain]

That is the struct of tables:

```
    'CREATE TABLE `project` (
      `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
      `Url` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Region` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `Area` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Description` text,
      `AccountId` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
      `UserId` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `ModifiedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `DeletedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `Deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
      `Likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Views` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Private` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
      `OnlyBudget` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
      KEY `dateproject` (`Date`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'


'CREATE TABLE `projectitem` (
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `BrandId` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SpecificationId` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectId` char(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`ProjectId`,`SpecificationId`),
  KEY `project_item_key_idx` (`ProjectId`),
  KEY `brand_idx` (`BrandId`),
  KEY `spec_item_key_idx` (`SpecificationId`),
  CONSTRAINT `project_item_key` FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectId`) REFERENCES `project` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `spec_item_key` FOREIGN KEY (`SpecificationId`) REFERENCES `specification` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

How I can improve that? I thing that one reason for the bad performance is because the lenght of my key in "projectitem" table.

I migrated that data from another database. Than, first a created all tables without keys and after the migration I used that command for create keys and indexes:

```
 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

ALTER TABLE `projectitemreference` 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `ProjectId`, `ProjectItemId`, `SpecificationId`),
ADD INDEX `reference_item_key_idx` (`ProjectId` ASC, `ProjectItemId` ASC, `SpecificationId` ASC) VISIBLE
, LOCK = NONE;

ALTER TABLE `projectitemreference` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `reference_item_key`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectId` , `ProjectItemId` , `SpecificationId`)
  REFERENCES .`projectitem` (`ProjectId` , `Id` , `SpecificationId`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `reference_project_key`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectId`)
  REFERENCES .`project` (`Id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION, LOCK = NONE;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Can it be a problem?

Comment: Do all those IDs consist of 36 characters? And do you really need utf8mb4?

Comment: Yes, all IDs consist of 36 characters because are GUIDs.
About utf8mb4, I think it insn't necessary. It's the pattern of MySQL Workbench, when I created tables.
Can it be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that's likely the default charset in Workbench and the MySQL version you use. But you can always define the GUID columns with ASCII charset. This means 1 byte per character and not 1 to 4. While the actual size on disk may be the same (not sure about that), it makes a difference in memory usage. And smaller indexes means more indexes kept on memory and faster queries.

Comment: Even better it would be use binary(16). See this article: https://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/

Comment: For the specific query, I think a composite index on `(projectid, brandid)` would help. (and you can see why a 32-bytes-per-row index will perform better than a 288-bytes-per-row one).

Comment: How big (GB) are the tables?  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: The table "project" has 3.95GB and "projectitem" has 8.15GB.
That server has 16GB of RAM. Can I increase the RAM usage limit? Will this improve the performance?
I've already change my ID's columns to binary(16). And it's improved my queries.

Answer (score 1):

`count(i.BrandId)` checks `BrandId` for being not null before counting.  If you don't need that check, change to `COUNT(*)` to count the number of rows in the `JOIN`.  Or perhaps you wanted `COUNT(DISTINCT i.BrandId)` to count the number of different brands?

Then these indexes will help:

```
project:  INDEX(Date)
projectitem:  INDEX(projectid)           -- if using COUNT(*)
projectitem:  INDEX(projectid, BrandId)  -- if explicitly COUNTing on BrandId
```

When you dataset gets bigger than RAM, the GUIDs will kill performance due to the random accesses blowing out the cache.

Be aware that any change, even a minor change, to those queries may necessitate reevaluation of the indexes.